# Click a button on a webpage

Tags: java

I'm using the `Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec` to open a webpage. What event handler would I use to click a button on the open webpage using Java?

Comment: What's the bigger goal you're trying to accomplish? Have you considered using a headless browser instead?

Comment: Job for [Selenium](http://openwritings.net/public/selenium/first-selenium-application-java)!

Answer (score 2):

None, really. You don't have any such fine-grained control over a process you initiate; all you get are the input, output, and error streams from the process.

If you want to interact with webpages from Java (but not display them on the screen), you can have a look at [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

You can configure HtmlUnit to impersonate a specific browser (user agent header, cookie policy, etc).

If all else fails, you could write a small JavaScript controller and open that in a browser instead of the target web page directly. That JavaScript controller could then talk back to your application, get instructions (like what page to navigate to), and act on those. [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) is a good candidate for that, but will probably require you to install a browser plugin.

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is to login to surveymonkey and download an excel file. I have program that will do this already but it will not work with in my Work domain because of bluecoat security because of a lack of a browser. So I thought if I could open and control it from the browser it would work that way. Thoughts?

Comment: @patrick - how exactly do they detect a "lack of browser" ? anyway, i've updated my answer with another approach

Comment: I think javascript may make this project get out of hand. Maybe not though. But what I meant by a lack of browser are the authentication certificates associated with a users credentials in the browser. I can post you the error I get if you think it helps. Because my code otherwise works fine, just not when I try and run it from my works domain.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the answer and comments from radai

a. "have program that will do this already but it will not work with in my Work domain because of bluecoat security because of a lack of a browser" - This is not because of the lack of browser. It is because your java process does not have the proxy credentials to hit the page. The http calls going from the tool, is directed through your proxy. You can try setting the environment with required properties.

If you are running the tool from command line - You can try something like this

```
JAVA_FLAGS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.100 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8800
java ${JAVA_FLAGS} <java_class_to_run>
```

b. If you are planning to re-create the tool - [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is another great option

Comment: I am planning to run from the command line. I will check in to this.

Comment: could you be a little more specific on how to add the proxy? I am a little unclear on it?

Comment: All the calls going from your machine/any machines in your network would pass have to passthrough the bluecoat proxy to hit the external site. In your tool's case,since you have not provided the proxy server details, the call is not going outside of your network.

Comment: you can get your proxy host and port details from you network admin and replace the values for host and port in answer

Comment: Ah ok that makes more sense. I'll see if I can go that route. Thanks for the info.